# ExpressJS sessions with cookies

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

Im trying to use cookies to stablish a user session with ExpressJS 4.2 and cookier-parser but all the documentation that I found is for Expressjs 3.x or older.

Can someone point me in the right direction whith this?

Doc or code snippet will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

======

I want to use PassportJS to authenticate local users with MongoDB, everything works fine excepts this route (ensureAuthenticatad always redirect to /, even when the user/pass is found in MongoDB

```
// reusable middleware
function ensureAuthenticated(req,res,next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {return next();}
        res.redirect('/'); // if failed...
    }


router.get('/panel', ensureAuthenticated,function(req, res){

    res.render('panel', {obj: testArr});

});
```

And thats because ensureAuthenticated cant find active cookies.

My app.js configuration is this:

```
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var favicon      = require('static-favicon');
var logger       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var passport     = require('passport')
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var flash        = require('connect-flash');


//Routes
//=====================================================================
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var admin  = require('./routes/admin');
var panel  = require('./routes/panel');



//Express configuration
//======================================================================
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

/*app.use(favicon());*/
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/', admin);
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're trying to do? The documentation that they have on the [parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) is pretty much the same as 3.x.

Comment: Yes, let me edit the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-session to initialize cookies based sessions

```
var session = require('express-session');
//code
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I did:
"express-session": "latest",
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat'}));
But the problem persist, im logged in, cookie set but I still get 304 from /panel

Comment: initialize it before passportjs initialization. I'm sending link how it worked for me https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/lib/generators/http/expressApp.js#L119